# Сортировка списка python

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, list, список

У меня есть список `list_access` из таких элементов
`((name, description, str(number), row))`.

Я пробовал сортировать этот список по полю `number` двумя способами:

1. `list_access.sort(key=lambda item: item[2])`
2. `list_access.sort(key=itemgetter(2))`

Но в обоих случаях список не сортируется и остается без изменений.

Подскажите пожалуйста - почему?

Comment: Покажите ваш код. Желательно - с теми данными, на которых вы пробуете.

Answer (score 0):

Сортировка по ключу:

```
list_access = [
    (('name', 'description', str(2), 1)),
    (('name', 'description', str(1), 2)),
    (('name', 'description', str(6), 3)),
    (('name', 'description', str(3), 4)),
]
print(list_access)

list_access.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])

print(list_access)
```

Результат:

```
[('name', 'description', '2', 1), ('name', 'description', '1', 2), ('name', 'description', '6', 3), ('name', 'description', '3', 4)]
[('name', 'description', '1', 2), ('name', 'description', '2', 1), ('name', 'description', '3', 4), ('name', 'description', '6', 3)]
```

---

**PS.**

Тут скобки лишние `(('name', 'description', str(2), 1))`, правильно так: `('name', 'description', str(2), 1)`. Такие лишние скобки не повлияют на код, но они мешают и легко из них случайно сделать кортеж, добавив запятую: `(('name', 'description', str(2), 1),)`